# How to concat sub object array inside object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I would like to concat sub object array inside object in javascript.
I have an object array inside an object: 
I would like to return the department sub array into one object array.

```
var array =
    {
      "departsObjInput": { 
        "departmentRequests": [
          {
            "department": [
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "20",
                  "groupName": "Group20",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "21",
                  "groupName": "Group21",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "24",              
                  "groupName": "Group24",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING" 
                }
              ],
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "18",
                  "groupName": "Group18",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "26",
                  "groupName": "Group26",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"
                }
              ]
            ] 
          },
          {
            "department": [
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "90",
                  "groupName": "Group90",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "38",
                  "groupName": "Group38",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                }
              ],
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "37",
                  "groupName": "Group37",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                }
              ]
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I would like to concat sub array of department like :

```
  {
  "departsObjInput": { 
    "departmentRequests": [
      {
        "department":  
          [
            {
              "groupID": "20",
              "groupName": "Group20",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
            },
            {
              "groupID": "21",
              "groupName": "Group21",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
            },
            {
              "groupID": "24",              
              "groupName": "Group24",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING" 
            },          
            {
              "groupID": "18",
              "groupName": "Group18",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
            },
            {
              "groupID": "26",
              "groupName": "Group26",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING"
            }
          ]

      },
      {
        "department":  
          [
            {
              "groupID": "90",
              "groupName": "Group90",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING",
            },
            {
              "groupID": "38",
              "groupName": "Group38",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING",
            },           
            {
              "groupID": "37",
              "groupName": "Group37",
              "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
              "deptStatus": "PENDING",
            }
          ]
         ,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what I tried to  :

```
var deptItem = array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests
var merged = [].concat.apply([], deptItem);
return merged;
```

I tried other scritps but I could not get the answer.
Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `forEach` loop to access each `department` array then make it single 1D array using `flat()`

```
array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests.forEach(x => {
  x.department = x.department.flat();
})
```

```js
var array =
    {
      "departsObjInput": { 
        "departmentRequests": [
          {
            "department": [
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "20",
                  "groupName": "Group20",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "21",
                  "groupName": "Group21",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "24",              
                  "groupName": "Group24",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING" 
                }
              ],
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "18",
                  "groupName": "Group18",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"  
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "26",
                  "groupName": "Group26",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING"
                }
              ]
            ] 
          },
          {
            "department": [
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "90",
                  "groupName": "Group90",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                },
                {
                  "groupID": "38",
                  "groupName": "Group38",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                }
              ],
              [
                {
                  "groupID": "37",
                  "groupName": "Group37",
                  "requestDate": "2020-01-21",
                  "deptStatus": "PENDING",
                }
              ]
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    
array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests.forEach(x => {
  x.department = x.department.flat();
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

The array is in `array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests.department`.

And `departmentRequests` is an array, you need to index it.

```
array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests[i].department = [].concat(...array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests[i].department);
```

Comment: Sir `array.departsObjInput.departmentRequests` is an array you need to loop through it.